# Extract XML from UIWebView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiwebview

I'm trying to extract some XML from a `UIWebView`, and not having much luck. This is what the entire document looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<authResponse xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <firstName>Name here</firstName>
  <lastName>Name here</lastName>
  <membershipTier>Membership level</membershipTier>
  <errorMessage />
  <isValid>1</isValid>
</authResponse>
```

I have tried a number of variations of the `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString` method, but this is the only one that will return anything for me:

```
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.documentElement.textContent"]
```

However, I need the raw XML, not the text content. Any suggestions?

**EDIT**: I have control over the XML, so it can be modified if need be.\

**EDIT 2**: As requested, code I am using to load the request is below. Note that this request is for a login screen. Once the user has entered their credentials, the page after that is the one I am trying to extract the results from. I determine which is the current page in `webViewDidFinishLoad` by testing the current `mainDocumentURL` for the `UIWebView` object.

```
    NSString* urlString = kLoginURL;
    NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    NSURLRequest* request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    UIWebView* tmpWebView = [[UIWebView alloc] init];
    self.webView = tmpWebView;
    [tmpWebView release];
    self.webView.delegate = self;
    [self.webView loadRequest:request];
```

Comment: What is the "raw" XML you need to extract, vs. the textual content you are getting? What do you expect the output to look like, vs, what you are in fact getting?

Comment: The output I am getting is exactly the XML I have included in the question. This is inside the UIWebView, and I want to get it into an NSString,

Comment: please can you add a link to  your server hosting this 'XML'. The text returned from your above javascript will be the raw HTML which includes the raw XML.

Comment: Sorry, I can't link to the server - it's an internally hosted process. The text returned from the above javascript is just that, text - no tags. So effectively what I get back is "Name here\nName here\nMembership level\n\n1

Comment: It would be ideal if you could make this request manually, using NSURLConnection, since UIWebView may simply not have a feature to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just wrote a little test program to figure this out (fun!).  It loads the UIWebView contents via:

```
 NSString * data = @"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><authResponse xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\"><firstName>Name here</firstName><lastName>Name here</lastName><membershipTier>Membership level</membershipTier><errorMessage /><isValid>1</isValid></authResponse>";
[self.webview loadHTMLString: data baseURL: nil];
```

I then passed the string `document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML` to `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString`

and it returns what you want:

```
<authresponse xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><firstname>Name here</firstname><lastname>Name here</lastname><membershiptier>Membership level</membershiptier><errormessage><isvalid>1</isvalid></errormessage></authresponse>
```

Comment: Hmm - first of all thank you so much for the effort you put in. Much appreciated. Unfortunately this test case is not quite the same, as loading an NSString* into a UIWebView seems to automatically insert <head></head><body> and </body> around the content if it's not present. This is why your javascript suceeds, as the body tag exists. In my response, it does not. As mentioned though, I do have control of the XML so I could insert it the head and body tags and solve this problem (which I probably will do). It feels a bit like a hack, though. Maybe there is no other option?

Comment: This got me closest to the solution I needed - so please enjoy your well deserved bounty!

Comment: thanks, it was fun :)  The problem seems to be that as raw xml it's not being parsed into a DOM tree, or at least that's what it seems like.  Loading it into Desktop safari seems to have the same problem (it'll give an error about no style information and then wrap it in HTML like you noted).

Comment: The key, I think, is that the DOM object tree in this case is an XML DOM tree and not an HTML DOM tree (but I'm a Mac & iOS guy, not a web guy!).

Comment: The data is there, just hard to get to.  For example, `document.childNodes[0].attributes[0].name.toString()` returns "xmlns:xsd" which is the first attribute of the authResponse node.

Comment: This loading your xml document from a local web server, so no automatic html tags added to it.

Comment: Yah, so it's xmldom.  this page is pretty helpful (especially the source of the tests):  http://www.grauw.nl/articles/xmldom/  in particular, `document.getElementsByTagName('firstName')[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue.toString()` returns "Name here" as you'd expect.  So you could write a javascript function to essentially extract the xml from the xml dom.  So you can get the individual pieces, if you know the structure.  Wrapping it in html seems easiest though...

Comment: well holy snapdragons, here's your answer for real!  `return (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(xmlNode)`  Just tested and it works great.  now I can go to sleep :-)

Comment: `2011-10-19 01:46:57.465 UIWebViewtest[16627:207] text is:

(new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(document.documentElement)

2011-10-19 01:46:57.466 UIWebViewtest[16627:207] result is: 

<authResponse xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <firstName>Name here</firstName>
  <lastName>Name here</lastName>
  <membershipTier>Membership level</membershipTier>
  <errorMessage/>
  <isValid>1</isValid>
</authResponse>
`

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Glad to know there is a solution, it seemed a little crazy that it wouldn't be possible.

Comment: I should clarify since xmlNode was part of a more complex test the line above won't actually work as is; replace `xmlNode` with `document` so the single line that works is:  `(new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(document)`

Comment: I actually ended up wrapping the XML in a body tag, but thanks for the clarification!

Comment: @alku3 I thought you said there was no body tag. Otherwise the solution I suggested does the same thing!

Answer (score 1):

You can try using [kissxml](http://code.google.com/p/kissxml/source/checkout) to retrieve the whole xml structure.

Or you can just save the response into a string from your NSURLRequest or if you are using other libraries to do a http connection

```
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://www.w3schools.com/xml/note.xml"];
NSString *myString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:(NSURL*)url] encoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding];
```

The code above is a sample on how you can retrieve the xml structure. This is much easier than using uiwebview.  The sample xml encoding is using ISO-8859-1 so you have to set the correct encoding so that the data will be readable

Comment: Unfortunately for other reasons, I need to use a UIWebView.

Comment: No, I dont want to display it, I want to extract it to something like an NSString, so I can process it.

Comment: Just set the result to a NSString and then process it afterwards.  Results from an HTTP request will always be in a raw format, either its a xml, a json or a html response

Comment: The whole point of my question is how to get the result from the UIWebView into an NSString.

Comment: check the codes above. It's much simpler than using uiwebview

Comment: Maybe in a simple case, but I need to allow the user to interact with the UIWebView first.

Answer (score 1):

i'd grab the whole html as a string on a seperate thread, or use this as the basis to load the webview:

```
NSString *xmlString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:yourURL]
```

Comment: The XML snippet in my question is the whole html - there's nothing else. And, I believe I need to go through a UIWebView for other reasons (I'm doing an automatic https login using javascript manipulation - once the login succeeds, I get back the XML mentioned above).

Comment: I think there is some misunderstanding in your requirements. If you want to extract a user entered value from the newly loaded webview then use ```NSString *userInput = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: @"document.getElementById('your div id here').textContent"]; ``` from my understanding of your request Shri's answer is what you need. else please elaborate.

Comment: I've pasted in the XML that I receive in the question, so there is no div ID, or any IDs I can use. The XML fragment in the question is the entire response. Unfortunately as I mentioned in the comments on Shri's answer, neither of those return anything for this XML fragment.

Comment: I think this is the confusion. The answers given will get you the raw xml from the newly loaded webview. If you need to parse this data then this would be trivial and has been covered on many other overflow requests. Hope this is what you need to hear?

Comment: I have no problem parsing the data. The answers given do not give me the raw XML - maybe they should, but they don't. The only way I've been able to get anything out of the UIWebView so far is by using the javascript in my original question. The other javascript answers unfortunately just return nil.

Comment: Sorry, they return a blank string, not nil.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest going with Nik's suggestion - get the request URL and get its content in an NSString.

OR you can send a request to the login URL (you are already intercepting the requests being sent) and get a response in a string.

If you want to read the entire body tag's content or the html and body tag's content, you might just do this

```
NSString *html = [yourWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.innerHTML"];
```

or

```
NSString *html = [yourWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.all[0].innerHTML"];
```

Comment: There is no body tag or html - all I'm getting back is that XML in my question - this is the entire response. Unfortunately, both those javascript strings you provided both return an empty string. The only way I've been able to extract anything from the UIWebView so far is using the javascript in my original question.

Comment: Try using the 1st suggestion then - send a request to the URL and get its response as an NSString. If the issue is that you need to submit a request in order to get the XML, you can easily do that using ASIFormDataRequest

Answer (score 0):

You can use either of these as per your need:

```
NSString *html1 = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: 
                  @"document.body.innerHTML"];

NSString *html2 = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: 
                  @"document.documentElement.outerHTML"];
```

Comment: Where are you using this code?? you should use this only when the view is loaded. Like in webView's delegate method "webViewDidFinishLoad".

Comment: Yes, that is exactly the method where I am using it. It returns content if I used the string mentioned in my question, but not the strings mentioned here.

Comment: Can you post some code where you are actually loading the webView(Calling loadRequest).